# Prisma query with select

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, prisma

I have Prisma models that are related, User, Car and Reservation:

```
model User {
  id              String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name            String?
  email           String?   @unique
  emailVerified   DateTime?
  image           String?
  hashedPassword  String?
  isAdmin         Boolean
  createdAt       DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt       DateTime @updatedAt
  favoriteIds     String[] @db.ObjectId

  accounts Account[]
  reservations Reservation[]
}
```

```
model Reservation {
  id String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  userId String @db.ObjectId
  carId String @db.ObjectId  
  startDate DateTime
  endDate DateTime
  totalPrice Int
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  options String[]
  fullName String
  phoneNumber String
  email String
  remarks String

  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  car Car @relation(fields: [carId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}
```

```
model Car {
  id String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  maker String
  model String
  category String
  type String
  imgSrc String[]
  horsePower Int
  year Int
  color String
  seatsCount Int
  doorsCount Int
  fuel String
  availableCount Int
  price Int

  reservations Reservation[]
}
```

In my code I do a findUnique query over my MongoDB to get the current user and I use select to have specific fields(I don't want to get the dates and email)

```
const currentUser = await prisma.user.findUnique({
            where: {
                email: session.user.email as string,
            },
            select: {
                name: true,
                isAdmin: true,
                favoriteIds: true,
                reservations: true,
                accounts: true,
                image: true,
            }
        })
```

but the problem is that in TS I get an error when I pass currentUser to different components, it doesn't crash the project but I want to get rid of it as it's annoying to see all the time:[image]

I tried creating a type which omits the fields I don't want but I still get the not assignable error.

```
export type SafeUserSelected = Omit<User, 
    "email" | "emailVerified" | "hashedPassword" | "createdAt" | "updatedAt" >
```

Any clues why this happens and how to fix it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can hover your mouse over the currentUser variable and see the exact type that prisma returns if you use select.

[image: Prisma user]

You can then copy it and make your custom type

```
export interface myUser {
name: string;
id: number;
//...
}
```

Or in your case, when you inspect the User type that prisma returns, you can see that it only has simple types:

```
export type Person = {
  id: number
  name: string
  password: string | null
  email: string
  roleId: number
  created: Date
  updated: Date | null
  expired: Date | null
  subjectId: number | null
  validated: boolean
  googleId: string | null
  facebookId: string | null
  appleId: string | null
}
```

You probably just forgot to omit some of them

Also, make sure that the components are actually expecting SafeUserSelected, and that the data you are providing is typed as SafeUserSelected.

Update your code with that component so we can check it.